# Do both lines return a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently following through the beginner Codebat track.  Both pieces of code work however is there anything fundamentally wrong/different between the two ways of writing the below code?

thanks,

```
def mine(myStr, x):
    myResult = myStr * x
    return myResult


def codebat(thierStr, i):
    codeResult = ''
    for i in range(i):
        codeResult += thierStr
    return codeResult
```

Comment: Both functions work and do the same thing, but the 2nd one has a horrible time complexity and should be avoided.

Comment: I assume in the first one you mean `myStr * x`? Otherwise they don't do quite the same thing.

Comment: First is more pythonic.

Comment: The second is awful. As @Aran-Fey already pointed out it has poor time complexity. Also the for loop overwrites the value of `i` such that when the loop terminates `i` is one less than the value passed to the function. If code further down in that function required (or assumed) the original value of `i` it would be lost.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import string  # string.ascii_letters = 'abcde...ABCDE...'

def mine(s, x):
    return s * x  # fixed your code so it multiplies by x, not 4

def theirs(s, x):  # renamed but the same as codebat
    res = ''
    for _ in range(x):
        res += s
    return res
```

We can see they give the same results

```
mine(string.ascii_letters, 10) == theirs(string.ascii_letters, 10) # --> True
```

We can test the time efficiency of these functions however

```
%timeit mine(string.ascii_letters, 1000)
2.27 µs ± 9.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit theirs(string.ascii_letters, 1000)
202 µs ± 4.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As you can see `mine` is almost 100 times more efficient because under the hood python pre-allocates the memory needed for the new string. In `theirs` it has to keep reallocating memory each time the string length is increased.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks!